# How to print 12 12 12..... using two threads in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-synchronization

How can I print 12 12 12....continuously using two threads in C++11.
can someone please suggest.
I have used two functions. One function will print "1" and the second function will print "2" with a condition variable. I don't know whether this is a correct approach or not

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

mutex m;
condition_variable cv;
bool flag = false;

void func1(int i)
{
    while(1)
    {
            unique_lock<mutex> lg(m);
            cout << i;
            if(flag)
                flag = false;
            else
                flag = true;
            lg.unlock();
            cv.notify_one();
    }
}

void func2(int i)
{
    while(1)
    {
            unique_lock<mutex> ul(m);
            cv.wait(ul, [](){return (flag == true) ? true : false;});
            cout << i;
            ul.unlock();
            //this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000));
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread th1(func1, 1);
    thread th2(func2, 2);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(flag == true) ? true : false`: Not related to the question, but think about this for a moment and what it really does. I am sure there is a much simpler way to write this.

Comment: @user17732522 `flag == true ? true : flag == false ? false : true;`?

Comment: If you want to repeatedly print the pattern alternating between the two functions, why do the two functions look so different? Shouldn't they look the same except that they wait on and set the opposite state of the flag? Why does `func1` have no `wait` and `func2` no `notify`?

Comment: Why did you write two completely different functions when you want each of the two threads to be doing essentially the same thing? The thing that you want each of the two threads to do is; (a) await its turn, (b) print its number, and then (c) tell the other thread, "now it's your turn."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the flag to be toggled by each thread, then each one should wait for the flag to have the correct value. The code below should make the job

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

mutex m;
condition_variable cv;
bool flag = false;

void func1(int i)
{
    while (1)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lg(m);
        cv.wait(lg, []() {return (flag == false) ? true : false; });
        cout << i;
        flag = true;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(200));
        lg.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}

void func2(int i)
{
    while (1)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> ul(m);
        cv.wait(ul, []() {return (flag == true) ? true : false; });
        cout << i;
        flag = false;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(200));
        ul.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread th1(func1, 1);
    thread th2(func2, 2);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    return 0;
}
```